# Найти все слова в тексте, начинающиеся c буквы "C" и заканчиваются буквой "A"

Tags: c++, строки

Вот до такого додумался, думал делать так найти первую букву потом перезаписать в обратно порядке, а потом опять найти первую, но не работает(

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
const int  S_BUF =  255;
int main(){
char str[S_BUF];
cout<<"input text: "; cin.getline(str,255);
unsigned int len = strlen(str);

unsigned int i;
int x = 0;
if(str[0]=='c')x++;
for(i = 0 ; i < len; i++ )if(str[i]==' '&&str[i+1]=='c')x++;
strrev(str);

unsigned int j;
int y = 0;
if(str[0]=='a')y++;
for(j = 0 ; j < len; i++ )if(str[j]==' '&&str[j+1]=='a')y++;

cout<<"count words on (a) "<<y<<endl;
cout<<"count words on (c) "<<x<<endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: А почему просто не разбить строку на слова, поместив их в отдельный массив строк, а затем не сравнить первый и последний символ каждого слова с требуемыми по заданию?

Comment: А можно пример кода?

Comment: А почему бы просто не использовать регулярные выражения и не заменить весь этот алгоритм парой строк?

Answer (score 3):

1. Пока не конец ввода, ищите начало слова.
2. Если первая буква не "с" идете в пункт 1. Иначе получили индекс начала слова.
3. Пока не конец ввода, ищите конец слова.
4. Если конец слова не "а" идете в пункт 1. Иначе получили индекс конца слова.
5. Делаете substr от начала до конца слова по полученным индексам.
6. Печатаете(записываете в массив) слово. идете в пункт 1.

Вместо 5-го пункта можете накапливать символы в буфер в п.3.

ЗЫ на примеры кода для учебного задания особо не рассчитывайте.

Comment: Спасибо, буду дерзать)